# Angular Reactive form subject not updating ui andalso reseting validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I enter address field with 25 characters as am setting address maxlen to 25 initially in ngOninit but on some condition from other component i hit a subject LenError from service and trying to change maxlen to 19. Now form goes invalid as i have changed maxlength from 25 to 19 and address box already have 25 characters. But when i click address box and press backspace i remove just one character making it a total of 24 which makes form valid ideally it should be invalid as i have set maxlen to 19.

I am not able to get whats wrong in my code. Please help.

```js
// LenError Subject Subscribe call inside Oninit
this.service.LenError.subscribe(error => this.setValidation() );

// Form Group
this.maxLen = 25;
this.Form = this.fb.group({
      address: ['', [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('^[ a-zA-Z0-9-_!@&*)(+=|/<>?,:;."\\\']+$'),
      Validators.maxLength(this.maxLen)]],
    });


// setValidation Function
setValidation() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const Ele = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#address');
      const EleControl = this.Form.get('address');
      this.maxLen = 19;
      EleControl.clearValidators();
      EleControl.setValidators([Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('^[ a-zA-Z0-9-_!@&*)(+=|/<>?,:;."\\\']+$'),
      Validators.maxLength(this.dbaNameMaxLen)]);
      EleControl.updateValueAndValidity();
      Ele.focus();
      Ele.maxLength = this.maxLen;
      this.chck = true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: let me try as its a huge code